# i18next internationalization chinese garbled

Tags: internationalization, i18next

I use i18next in sitewhere,in translation.json in the following figure:

"Username":"用户名",
    "Password":"密码",

page displays the following figure:

�û���
����

Is a piece of garbage!
Here is my javascript code:

```js
$(function() {
   var option = {
     lng: lng,
     resGetPath: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/locales/__lng__/translation.json',
     useLocalStorage: false,
     lowerCaseLng: true
   };
   i18n.init(option, function(t) {
     $("body").i18n();
     i18next = t;
   });
 });
```

Who can help me how to configure?Thinks all...

Comment: What encoding did you save that file in? What encoding did you set for your website. Do other Chinese characters in the HTML show up correctly?

Comment: Sounds like you aren't declaring the page charset properly.

Comment: Sorry.. My application is gbk encoding,so the problem was caused by the above!Should I use utf8 coding.But thinks all